# Wp Cron job - error

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am trying to create a cron job by  following  command in cpanl but its throwing error[image]
none of following command is working , any help will be appreciated.

```
* * * * * cd /home/ausanabo/public_html/; php -q wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1

# Alternative command:
 * * * * * wget -O - "https://www.ausanabolics.is/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Change to `wget -O - "https://www.ausanabolics.is/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron" 2>&1 > /dev/null`

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

This code i already used in my project. This code is working.

/usr/bin/php -q /home/domain_name/public_html/folder_name/php_file_name.php /dev/null 2>&1